# HTTP Response header - how to retrieve particular value from the HTTP Response Header java

Tags: java, http-headers, json-deserialization

passing the secret key in the rest service and check the response code
if the response code = 200 then i collect all the HTTP Response Header

```
if (responseCode == 200) {
            bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
     String output;
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
     while ((output = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) 
          builder.append(output);
     System.out.println(builder.toString());     
}
```

output

```
{ "issued_at" : "1470049186841", 
  "scope" : "core",
 "status" : "approved", 
 "api_product_list" : "[prod]", 
 "expires_in" : "1199", 
 "token_type" : "BearerToken",
 "access_token" : "mX1GlCBhipXSeGi7YRBAr0KvS03J",  
 "refresh_token_expires_in" : "0",
 "refresh_count" : "0"}
```

from the output i want to pick only the access_token value

Note: below are the salesforce code, i want to convert into java

```
 Map<String,String> responseMap= new Map<String,String>())JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),Map<String,String>.class);
            return responseMap.get("access_token");
```

Updated: gson api code below

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
            Map<String, Object> map78 = new HashMap<>();
            map78 = (Map<String, Object>) gson.fromJson(output, map.getClass());
```

but i am getting null value

Comment: Look for the google gson api, check the "gson.fromJson()" function

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();
            Map<String, Object> map78 = new HashMap<>();
            map78 = (Map<String, Object>) gson.fromJson(output, map.getClass());

Comment: i am getting null value, is this correct (code pasted in the above as well as in my question

Answer (score 0):

with help of Marcel i am getting the answer using gson

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        String output = null;
        Map<String, Object> responseToken = new HashMap<>();
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(output);               
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();          
            responseToken = (Map<String, Object>) gson.fromJson(builder.toString(), responseToken.getClass());
            System.out.println("from map" + responseToken);
        }
        System.out.println ("access token Key "+responseToken.get("access_token"));
```